# Linux checksum of directory

Tags: python, linux, checksum

I need to check if a directory and all its sub-directories and files have had any changes to:

file permission
file name
file contents

I'd like to get a checksum out of it.

Using tar doesn't seem to work well, because it contains file modify time, and maybe access time too. I'm not sure. Python's checksumdir doesn't contain any metadata at all, not even file name.

Anyone know of a way to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use `tar` with `--mtime` flag and provide specific value to modification time. E.g. 1-1-70.

Comment: If you can run an external process, [mtree](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mtree) probably does what you want.

Comment: Thank you @TrishanshBhardwaj. This worked perfectly. Thank you also

Comment: Thank you also @MarkPlotnick

Comment: If this to detect if the directory tree has been modified? If so, you should consider using `inotify` rather than polling using a checksum.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tar` with `--mtime` flag and provide specific value to modification time. E.g. 1-1-70